# Android 2.1 bug: uses res/layout-v3 instead of res/layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In addition to the general `res/layout` folder I have a `res/layout-v3`
folder for backward compatibility with Android 1.5, which has problems
with some `RelativeLayout` layouts.

It works perfectly with all phones and emulator versions tested so
far. Except of 2.1 (emulator and Nexus One). They choose to display
the Android 1.5 layout (`res/layout-v3`) instead of the default `res/
layout`.

Can anyone else confirm that? Is this an Android OS bug? If so, where
is the best place to submit the bug report?

---

**UPDATE:**

After reading up on https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers again (thanks Mark for the hint), especially this part

> Resources that are for use only on a
>   specific API Level or higher. For
>   example, if your application is
>   designed to run on both Android 1.5
>   (API Level 3) and Android 1.6 (API
>   Level 4 and higher), you can use the
>   -v4 qualifier to tag any resources that should be excluded when your
>   application is running on Android 1.5
>   (API Level 3).

I changed my layout order from having

- res/layout-v3 (for Android 1.5 only -> this was a wrong assumption I made)
- res/layout (for anything else)

to my new configuration of having:

- res/layout-v4 (for Android 1.6 and higher)
- res/layout (for anything else -> in this case this would be Android 1.5 only)

If I understand the above documentation right and if my assumptions in the parentheses are correct this time it should work now. However, the result is the following:

- Android 1.5 is using res/layout -> OK
- Android 1.6 is using res/layout-v4 -> OK
- Android 2.0 is using res/layout -> **NOT OK**
- Android 2.1 is using res/layout-v4 -> OK

So why is Android 2.0 (on both Emulator and Motorola Milestone) not picking the right layout resource folder?

I tested it then again with 2.0.1 and it seems to work there. So that seems to be a bug in 2.0 which got fixed in 2.0.1

But now the weirdest thing: in order to make it somehow run on 2.0 I copied the res/layout-v4 folder to res/layout-v5 to force Android 2.0 using this layout resource. Didn't work. But then I tried copying it to res/layout-v6 (which is supposed to be Android 2.0.1) and voilà all the sudden it works with 2.0. Very strange! But I hope this workaround will help a few other people out there.

Comment: On the last point, http://b.android.com is the official issue tracker. If you can attach or point to a set of source code that reproduces the problem, that will help expedite analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested several devices and emulators (although not very thoroughly), and it seems that the selected resource folder is the one with the **higher version <= device version**.

Comment: To elaborate on Mr. Milano's answer, res/layout-v3 should be used by anything running Android 1.5 or higher. res/layout would be used by Android 1.1 or 1.0. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers for details ("Resources that are for use only on a specific API Level or higher. For example, if your application is designed to run on both Android 1.5 (API Level 3) and Android 1.6 (API Level 4 and higher), you can use the -v4 qualifier to tag any resources that should be excluded when your application is running on Android 1.5 (API Level 3).").

Comment: Thanks for the hint Mark and dtmilano. It helped solving the problem and creating a workaround for the bug. See my update in my question above.