# How can I create a single Android application that can handle the different screen resolutions seen on Android devices?

Tags: java, android

How can I create a single Android application that can handle the different screen resolutions seen on Android devices? I want my application to adapt to the different available resolutions.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8148760/1265724)

Comment: @user1877907 If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [how to support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Answer (score 0):

Read on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) here.

There it is described well how to create apps to support multiple screen sizes/resolution. I think this is an essential knowledge to have for android development.

Answer (score 0):

Create folders for each display resolution:

- small screen: **res->layout-ldpi** design for 240*320 resolution screen
- medium screen: **res-->layout-mdpi** design for 320*480 resolution screen
- large screen: **res-->layout-hdpi** design for 480*800 resolution screen

When you run your project, it automatically takes layout design from the required layout/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different layout folders and drawable resources to support multiple screen sizes on Android. [More on this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
    android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
    android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
    android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
    android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
    android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

And see below link for more information.

[Screen_Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)